# What can cause MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback not to work in IE9?

Tags: asp.net

I have the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True"` in the Page directive for one my aspx pages. On a postback it returns the original position before a postback in Chrome and FF but not in IE9 -- same is true for a jscript solution from [Mahdi Hasheminezhad](http://en.hasheminezhad.com/scrollsaver).

There was a time when either (Page directive or jscript) wasn't working, the fix was to add the site to the Trusted Sites Zone thru GP; either solution worked afterward. However, due to requirements I had to move the site to the Local Intranet Security Zone -- not sure if this where MaintainScrollPosition broke. The default security settings for Local Intranet Zone are "Medium-Low" so they should be lower than that of Trusted Sites, so it should work the same.

I tried this from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) but it didn't work.

What else can cause this not to work in IE9?

Comment: IE itself has always been a problem maker for me. Check this [An answer to Maintaining Scroll Position and Selected Control on Postback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880305/647884).

Comment: @RoboLover I took a look and noted the jscript work around would need to be applied to each page where I wanted to maintain scroll pos. The syntax recommendation in that post didn't work either. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: did you know this `Internet Explorer places restrictions on each Web page it opens. The restrictions are dependent upon the location of the Web page (Internet, Intranet, Local Machine zone, and so on). Web pages on the local computer have the fewest security restrictions and reside in the Local Machine zone, making the Local Machine security zone a prime target for malicious users. Zone Elevation also disables JavaScript navigation if there is no security context.` from [Internet Explorer Policy Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457144.aspx)